# Table not found Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a class DatabaseHandler. I have overridden the onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) method with the following code :

```
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_SONG + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                            SONG_TITLE + " TEXT," + ARTIST_NAME + " TEXT," + GENRE + " TEXT," +
                            SONG_PATH + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
```

but I found that there were extra items getting appended to the TABLE_SONG everytime I opened the emulator as a result of which even though I had 6 songs in the sdcard the database showed 454 songs. This forced me to drop the table with a thought of recreating it again. But now I am stuck that the table could not be found or rather is not getting created. Shouldnt it be that the onCreate() method should get called everytime when I create an object of this class?

Comment: try uninstalling and installing the app again

Comment: hi are you using SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: @DeepakSamuelRajan yes actually I am ... why?? :O

Comment: then you should upgrade using onUpgrade method and only Create table is enough check the sample below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with waqas please find sample code below

```
    @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
                    + ... ) ";
db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);}

@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if exists
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
                onCreate(db);
}
```

**EDIT**
USE of onUpgrade()

It is called when you construct a SQLiteOpenHelper with version newer than the version of the opened database. What to do depends on the changes in the database that are made between the old and new versions. The only case when you don't drop a changed table is when the change is noting more than an added column. Then you can use ALTER TABLE statement to add the new column to the table signature.

Comment: Okay so everytime I need to refresh the table I call onUpgrade() ??

Comment: any change made in older version will be upgraded using this method

Comment: hey how can reinstall the app... i am a noob...:/

Comment: if your using ICS 4+ just drag your app icon to uninstall on top right  or go to Setting->manage apps-> your app and click on uninstall

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18726/discussion-between-saurabh-and-deepak-samuel-rajan)

Answer (score 1):

Referring to `SQLiteOpenHelper` implementation, the `onCreate` method is called only once when it doesn't find the database file, causing it to create one. Later, `onUpgrade` is called whenever the database version number is found to be incremented.

To solve your problem quickly, simply uninstall and then install the app again. This will cause your database to go away, so allowing `onCreate` to be called once again.

Comment: I am newbie how do we do that?? Do I have to do it via command prompt??

Comment: simply go to Settings->Apps and find your app to proceed with uninstallation

Answer (score 0):

`onCreate` will not be called if the database has already been created, such as during the previous time you have run your application.

Either uninstall your app and install again - it will remove the db files as well

or increment your db version this will result in `onUpgrade` being called. In `onUpgrade` you can drop all your tables and call onCreate